# Polynomial in $\mathbb F[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm brushing up on algebra, reading over some questions I found online. I was wondering, if $p(x)\in \mathbb F[x]$, for some field $\mathbb F$, then what is $\langle p(x)\rangle$? Does it mean the elements like $p(x)+p(x)$, or elements like $p(x)p(x)$? Or something else? Thanks!

Comment: $\langle p(x)\rangle$ is the ideal generated by $p(x)$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I think that was the question ("What does the ideal generated by $p$ look like?").

Comment: Something else, in this case all polynomials of the shape $q(x)p(x)$ where $q(x)$ ranges over all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I considered adding more detail but I figured that the definition of an ideal would be hard to forget. I think of it like $p(x)\mathbb{F}[x]$.

Comment: Thank you all! I think I can take it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally in a commutative ring $R$ the ideal $\langle a_1,\ldots, a_n\rangle$ generated by the $a_i$ is the set of $R$-linear combinations $r_1a_1+\cdots + r_na_n$ for $r_i \in R$. If you are brushing up, you might as well check that this forms an ideal, and what this looks like in your particular case. You can reference [wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28ring_theory%29#Ideal_generated_by_a_set) for more information.